# Boost::asio not on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: c++, boost, debian

Boost::asio is included in Boost since version 1.35. However I cant find asio in the boost repositories for Debian Wheezy, although its version 1.48. Are they not supported?

Comment: It works on Linux Kernels 2.4 and 2.6 - so unlikly to be missing by design. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Debian Wheezy uses Boost 1.49.

The package [`libboost-all-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libboost-all-dev) will provide all boost development files, including boost::asio.

**Edit from comment:**

Package [libboost-all-dev](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libboost-all-dev) requires [libboost-dev](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libboost-dev), which requires [libboost1.49-dev](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libboost1.49-dev).  Boost::asio is there.

It will be installed to /usr/include/boost/

Comment: Thanks, I got [libboost-all-dev](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libboost-all-dev)(default package) which is not containing asio.

Comment: @DevNoob boost::asio is part of the libboost-dev package. Try: `ls /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp`, or `dpkg -L libboost-dev | grep asio` and you should see that it's installed.

Comment: I found the debian package using: `dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp`. It returned `libboost1.54-dev: /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp`